# How to reduce height of cell in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a area chart build with highcharts, I am trying to reduce some spaces between y axis cell columns  means reduce height from 0 to 1 , 1 to 2 etc, but not getting proper result. how to achieve it ?

[image]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var txt = document.getElementById('hdnYaxis');
            var txtFoxXAxis = document.getElementById('hdnXaxis');
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'area'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Status'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: $.parseJSON(txtFoxXAxis.value),
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            color: 'red'


                        }

                    },
                    maxPadding: 0,
                },

                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name} <b>{point.y:,.0f}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {

                        marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            radius: 2,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series:  $.parseJSON(txt.value)
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  you want to retain the ticks (1,2,3,4,5), but you want them closer together? That's a function of the height of the chart, and the margin/spacing at the top and bottom.  So if you want the same labels, but you want them taking up less space, either reduce the chart height, or increase the marginTop/marginBottom

Answer (score 0):

set tickPixelInterval in yAxis ,use this:

```
 yAxis: {
        tickPixelInterval: 10 // whatever you want
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set maxPadding on yAxis as 0.

```
yAxis:{
   maxPadding:0
}
```